# Android : First version of my app supports 2.3 and now I am planning to support only 4+ in next version

Tags: android, version

What will happen to the existing user in 2.3 android version
launching the newer version with 4 as minimum as android version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, they won't get the updates and they won't see your app again in the Google Play. They still can use it but if they uninstall it they can't find it to reinstall it.